# Is it possible to reconnect to a remote cmd.exe shell?

Tags: windows, ssh, remote, windows-command-prompt

I am using freesshd.com to run an ssh server on my machine. I need to be able to execute .bat files in their normal environemt so I am using the cmd.exe shell, the only shell I know of that can correctly execute .bat files. I have tried launching cmd.exe via a cygwin bash shell inside a mosh shell but that was a nightmare...

Anyway, similar to programs like mosh or screen, is there something that can resume a windows cmd.exe shell if the remote connection to it was closed? As it may be an interactive shell so getting back to its standard input may be pretty important. It's also nice to be able to resume a shell instead of reconnecting in a blank state.

Comment: Doesn't really apply to resuming a broken connection, but you should really look at using powershell.  If you have long running tasks you can run them in a background with the `-asjob` option.  So my suggestion is that it is time to upgrade your batch files to powershell.

Comment: This is a good solution for non-interactive programs. However there is still a need to resume interactive programs which would become stuck because they would wait forever on stdin input which is now lost.